# jquery show/hide large image with mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am using this jquery code to hide/show a image with fixed position:

```
$(document).on('mouseover',".multiverseid", function (e) {
  var mid = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#picture').attr('src', mid);
  $('.image-content').css("display", "flex");
});  
$(document).on('mouseout',".multiverseid", function (e) {
  $('#cardpicture').attr('src', "");
  $('.image-content').css("display", "none");
});
```

the code is working great as long as the image is preloaded. When I do the mouseover on a large picture that is not fully loaded the image do not appear and even staying on the mouseover area longer does not show up the image. i have to move out of the area and reenter the mouseover area to show it.

So I tried it with this code:

```
$(document).on('mouseover',".multiverseid", function (e) {
  var mid = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#picture').attr('src', mid);
  $("#picture").load(function() {
    $('.image-content').css("display", "flex");
  });  
});
$(document).on('mouseout',".multiverseid", function (e) {
  $('#cardpicture').attr('src', "");
  $('.image-content').css("display", "none");
});
```

but I had no success. Same issue. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remove the `src` attribute for that. It is enough to just hide the element with `display: none`.

Setting the `src` to an empty string actually cancels the load process and the browser probably keeps the "faulty" state in its cache.